# algorithm that finds the "mean positioned" white pixel in a column and repeats the process for each column

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am attempting to create an algorithm that locates the white pixels in a column of a binary image, and then adds the y co-ordinates/column number of each white pixel and divides this value by the number of white pixels in the column, in order to get the "mean/middle positioned" white pixel in the column. And this returns an (x,y) co-ordinate that can be plotted. This process repeats for each column in the image and each time sy sets back to 0.

The end goal is instead of having a lines that are multiple pixels thick/wide, as shown in the image's numpy array[current line multiple thicks wide array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C4I4.png), I have lines that are just one pixel wide, whilst mantaining the original shape. I planned on doing this by selecting the "mean positioned white pixel in each column". I will then use these pixels to obtain x and y co-ordinates to plot.
 Here is what I have

```
sx = x = img.shape[1]
sy = 0
whitec = cv2.countNonZero(img.shape[1])
arrayOfMeanY = [] #array to place (x,y) co-ordinate in

#Select column to iterate
for x in range(img.shape[1]):
    # iterating through individual items in the column
    for y in range(img.shape[0]): 
        # Checking for white pixels
        pixel = img[x,y] 
        if pixel == 255: 
            # Then we check the y values of the white pixels in the column and add them all up
            sy = sy+y 
            whitec +=1 
    # Doing the calculation for the mean and putting it into the meanY list
    sy = sy/whitec 
    y = sy
    print img[x,y] 
    array.append(y)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    # reset sy to 0 for the next column
    sy = 0
```

My issue is I recieve this error when I run the code:

```
File "<ipython-input-6-e4c2225ff632>", line 27, in <module>
        whitec = cv2.countNonZero(img.shape[1])  #n= number of white pixels 
in the column

    TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

How do I rectify this issue, and once  once this issue is rectified will my coding do what I described above.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: @Miki Valid point, I've edited the question to make it clearer hopefully

Answer (score 1):

No need for loops here. With `numpy` you hardly ever need to loop over individual pixels.

Instead, create a function which takes the mean of the locations of the non-zero pixels for each column (I converted to `np.intp` to index the image; you could just cast with `int()` but `np.intp` is what Numpy uses for indexing arrays so, it's slightly more appropriate).

```
def avgWhiteLocOverCol(col):
    return np.intp(np.mean(np.where(col)))
```

Then you can simply apply the function along all columns with [`np.apply_along_axis()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html).

```
avgRows = np.apply_along_axis(avgWhiteLocOverCol, 0, img)
```

For example, let's create an image with white pixels on the middle row and on the diagonal:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.eye(500)*255
img[249,:] = 255
cv2.imshow('',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Example image]

Then we can apply the function over each column, which should give a line with half the slope:

```
def avgWhiteLocOverCol(col):
    return int(np.mean(np.where(col)))

avgRows = np.apply_along_axis(avgWhiteLocOverCol, 0, img)

avgIndImg = np.zeros_like(img)
avgIndImg[avgRows,range(img.shape[1])] = 255

cv2.imshow('',avgIndImg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Example output image]

Comment: When I ran your code I got this error
        File "<ipython-input-7-f27c6b5da404>", line 31, in <module>
        avgIndImg[avgRows,range(leftline.shape[1])] = 255

       IndexError: index -9223372036854775808 is out of bounds for axis 0 
        with size 480

Comment: Note that I'm using `np.where(col)` because my script is just looking for non-zero values in each column. You might want to specifically find `np.where(col==255)`. I can't fully see why you're getting that error without seeing the image, but it seems like you have some fully black columns, in which case you need to decide what you want to do with that column... You can handle that case inside the function (e.g. `if (col==0).all(): ...`) and you can decide what you want to return in that case.

Comment: I am sort of getting what I want in that the lines are one pixel wide but I still wanted the original shape to be maintained  but instead I have one horizontal line, I've made alterations to my question so I'm hopefully clearer

Comment: I believe the issue might be because each time I've been specifying the rows and the columns its been for all the rows and all the columns as opposed to specific column I am calculating the mean for and then increasing it by one each time